# React Button disabled property not working on conditionals

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

I have a **DIV** which contain two child element. These elements are button and I want to add ***disabled*** property to these buttons on some conditions, when I apply conditions to these buttons it's not working.
I don't know why this is not working although conditions are correct.

My code is as follows :

```js
< div className = 'change-page' >
  <
  button
type = 'button'
disabled = {
  page === 0 ? 'true' : ''
}
onClick = {
    () => setPage(page > 1 ? page - 1 : 1)
  } >
  Prev <
  /button>

  <
  button
type = 'button'
onClick = {
  () => setPage(page + 1)
}
disabled = {
    next === 1 ? '' : 'true'
  } >
  Next <
  /button> <
  /div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Here **page === 0** means user is at the first page so, **prev** button should be disabled, same goes for **next** button if there is not next page available than this *next* button should **disabled.**

Please suggest a possible solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This: `() => setPage(page > 1 ? page - 1 : 1)` suggests your page indices are 1-based, thus `page` is never `0`. Not sure, what exactly is `next` value, but disabling *Next* button when `next` equals some specific number also looks suspicious.

Comment: This next state is set to 1 when my api return a boolean variable has_next true. This tells me that I have next page and I can click to next button. But when api return false in has_next, I set this next to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You set start page from **0**,
when page === 2 then set page returning 1.
and when page ===1 then , prev button assign 1 to the **page*

```
  () => setPage(page > 1 ? page - 1 : 1)
```

Here is my working code.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {

  const [page, setPage] = useState(1); // Starting from page 1
  const [next, setNext] = useState(1);
  return (
    <div className='change-page' >
      Page: {page} <br />
      Next: {next} <br />
      <button
        type='button'
        disabled={page === 1} // If page == 1 then disabled Button
        onClick={
          () => setPage(page > 1 ? page - 1 : 1)
        } >Prev </button>

      <button
        type='button'
        onClick={
          () => setPage(page + 1) // On next increment the page
        }
        disabled={next === 1 ? false : true} >
        Next </button>
    </div>
  )
}
export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Prev button and next button are not disabling. I understand your solution but problem still remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a boolean instead of a string:

```
disabled={page === 0}
```

Comment: Just `disabled={page===0}` will do.

Comment: Oh yeah, I tunnelvisioned. Thank you

Comment: I am sorry, I just tried but it's not working.

Comment: Double check the `page` value... If it is a string like `"0"`, the comparison should use 2 equal signs, not 3.

Comment: Yes setPage is working fine, I can go to next page on onClick() event.